# How to append data in session variable in php?

Tags: php, session

I'm developing shopping cart application. In this selected product ids are stored in session variable. If user wants to add another products in the cart he will click on **Add More...** button. I want to append selected product's ids in same session variable.

My code is:

shop_details_cart.php

```
$get_ids = $_GET['ids']; 
$ids =  json_decode($get_ids,true);
$id_string = implode(',', array_map(function ($entry) {
 return $entry['id'];
}, $ids));
//$_SESSION['ids'];
//array_push($_SESSION['ids'],$id_string);
$_SESSION['ids']=$id_string;
$sql=mysql_query("select product_id,name,stock from $shop_loc where product_id IN($_SESSION[ids])");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ids'])){
    $_SESSION['ids'].=$id_string.",";
} else {
    $_SESSION['ids']=$id_string.",";
}


$sql=mysql_query("select product_id,name,stock from $shop_loc where product_id IN(".trim($_SESSION[ids],",").")");
```

Comment: I modified your code like this- if(isset($_SESSION['ids'])){
        $_SESSION['ids'].=",".$id_string;
       } else {
        $_SESSION['ids']=",".$id_string;
       }
       echo $_SESSION['ids'];
       $sql=mysql_query("select product_id,name,stock from $shop_loc where product_id IN($_SESSION[ids])")or die(mysql_error());   but it gives $_SESSION['ids'] values like Array,133,134 and error 'Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause''

Comment: Why it gives 1st element Array in session variable?

Comment: That is because you are concatenating `(.)` `$_SESSION['ids']` without generating/assigning anything to it. That's why it gives either `Notice: Undefined index` or `empty array`. Let me know if anything confusive here.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155938/7439186 improve

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ids'])){
        $_SESSION['ids'].= ' , '.$id_string;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['ids']=$id_string;
    }


    $sql=mysql_query("select product_id,name,stock from $shop_loc where product_id IN(".trim($_SESSION[ids],",").")");
```

Comment: you could've just edited the original answer

Comment: @Mateja sorry i don't know how to do that why i did this on 2017 

Comment: ahhaha, okay. :)